# Turning a .then / .catch block of code into Async Await

Tags: javascript

to preface this, as I'm sure this will be a walk in the park for 99% of you guys, I'm quite new to JS and want to ensure I'm using all the syntactic sugar that I can to be up-to-date when the time comes for interviews and job prep etc.

As such, I was hoping someone would kindly help me turn the below app.post request, from a Promise .then, into an async / await (try, catch) function.

As a side-note, this small block is forming a very basic user authentication to a Mongo DB. I have a block of code that's for a new user to register, and I can write that with async / await just fine. I'm struggling with this part somehow.

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  User.findOne({ email: username })
    .then((foundUser) => {
      if (foundUser.password === password) {
        res.render("secrets");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I have essentially tried writing this a number of times and keep rendering the **(err)** instead of the page I want.

Comment: welcome! how did you rewrite it?

Comment: Can you please include your attempt at this? You said "*I tried writing this a number of times and keep rendering the (err) instead of the page I want.*" Include the code you used along with the error you got

Comment: FYI, [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/13927534). I didn't. I figured debugging your code to help you understand where you went wrong with your reasoning would have been more useful than giving you an example usage which honestly was a very simple google search away if that's what you wanted. Glad you got your answer anyway.

Comment: Hey Miss Skooter - I do really appreciate your offer to help debug my code. And I agree, if you know exactly what you want from google, it would be a very simple search. But as I'm still learning a lot of this stuff, I actually found most of the Stack Overflow posts to be more complicated than what I was trying to achieve. Thanks again though, have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  try {
    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: username });
    if (foundUser.password === password) {
      res.render('secrets');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'd been getting confused with where to put the 'await', and trying to add a function after the 'findOne' (not entirely sure why now that I look at this!!).